# Iterating over a tensor in python

Tags: python, numpy, iteration, tensor

I am trying to generalize the following code to order n tensors; code given is for order 3 tensors and given indices i,j,k:

```
# Given integers i,j,k,size
i,j,k,size = 3,4,5,6

matrix = np.zeros([size,size,size],dtype=bool) # Order 3 tensor with every entry set to False

matrix[:,j,k] = True
matrix[i,:,k] = True
matrix[i,j,:] = True
```

So basically I would like to iterate the ':' and fill the other arguments with fixed numbers, for a general tensor order. I am hoping for some elegant numpy functions if that's possible.

Comment: Can you please update your question with sample inputs and expected outputs?

Comment: You can just run the example code, I don't think it's too helpful though in this particular case.

Comment: Create indexing tuples like `(slice(None),j,k)`.  For example start with idx=`[i,j,k]`, replace one of the values with `slice(None)`, and `matrix(tuple(idx)] = ...`

Answer (score 0):

The answer by hpaulj is exactly what I what I was looking for, thank you so much!
This code could be made more efficient but it works.

```
# Given integers i,j,k,size
order = 5
i,j,k,l,m = 6,7,8,9,10

vector = [i,j,k,l,m]
matrix = np.zeros(order*[size],dtype=bool)

for DIM in range(len(size)):
  idx = vector.copy()
  idx[DIM] = slice(None)
  matrix[tuple(idx)] = True
```